# Search merge requests in a project for multiple User IDs from the Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to list all the merge requests from a list of user IDs/usernames for a given project ID. I'm looking at the Gitlab API to [list merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests) for a project (example below) but I don't see any option to search on multiple User IDs or usernames. The search on user ID is a string query parameter and does not have an option that takes a list of User IDs.

`https://<gitlab>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/merge_requests?author_username=my_git_username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to provide a list of user IDs.

You must either:

1. Request the endpoint multiple times for each user ID you want to list OR
2. Enumerate *all* merge requests then filter them by ID yourself

Comment: thank you very much!